# How to keep records in an excel file ON THE BASIS OF DUPLICACIES ONLY IN ONE COLUMN?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a binary excel file with more than 200,000 records with duplicate values **only in one column**(COLUMN A). I want to **keep only those** records corresponding to which the value in column A has **at least 4 repetitions anywhere in the whole column**. Could anyone please suggest me a way using excel formula or a small vb script. Even a link to some good place would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to make an effort to do this on your own. We generally don't write code for you, but rather help you address specific problems you're running into. To get started, you'll want to take a look at [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34). If you get stuck, edit your question to include what code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this formula all on `column B` (that could be other column of your choice)

1. B1= `countif($A:$A,A1)` then copy it all the way down where data are on Column A.
2. Filter Column B on Numbers > 4
3. Select filtered Rows, right-click, then delete.

Hope it helps.
Good Luck